# Set Stereo Rendering Mode in new XR Settings

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

The new XR settings do not have Single-Pass but instead has Single-Pass-Instanced and Multi-Pass. The library that I use works only on Single-Pass for Oculus Rift unfortunately. I was trying for a way to override it but I could not find any options to change to Single-Pass in the new XR system. I cannot go back to old XR System as its deprecated. I wanted to get your info for a solution for this. Is there a way to achieve this for Oculus?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR;

public class SteoreoRendering : MonoBehaviour
{
    XRSettings.StereoRenderingMode stereoRenderingMode;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(stereoRenderingMode);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible during runtime. `XRSettings.stereoRenderingMode` is read-only and cannot be modified.